# Why is the wrong function being executed?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, multiple-inheritance

I ran into a confusing situation today that I'm hoping someone can explain to me.

I have a C++ program with 4 classes:

- A `Base` class that just acts as a common interface,
- An `Enroll` class, which subclasses `Base` and has a pure virtual `enroll()` method,
- A `Verify` class, which also subclasses `Base` and has a pure virtual `verify()` method,
- A `Both` class that subclasses both `Enroll` and `Verify` and provides implementations for `enroll()` and `verify()`

Like so:

```
 class Base {
    public:
       Base () { }
       virtual ~Base () { }
 };

 class Enroll : public virtual Base {
    public:
       virtual ~Enroll () { }
       virtual void enroll () = 0;
 };

 class Verify : public virtual Base {
    public:
       virtual ~Verify () { }
       virtual void verify () = 0;
 };

 class Both : public Enroll, public Verify {
    public:
       virtual ~Both () { }

       virtual void enroll () { printf ("Enrolling.\n"); }
       virtual void verify () { printf ("Verifying.\n"); }
 };
```

Instances of `Both` are instantiated in a non-member function, which just creates a new `Both` and returns the pointer:

```
Both* createInstanceOfBoth () {
   return new Both();
}
```

Finally, there's a `Registry` class that basically just acts as an `Enroll`/`Verify` factory.  It uses a pair of function pointers to the `createInstanceOfBoth()` function to provide an instance of `Enroll` or `Verify`:

```
typedef Enroll* (*EnrollGenerator) ();
typedef Verify* (*VerifyGenerator) ();

class Registry {
   public:
      Registry () {
          enrollGenerator = (EnrollGenerator)&createInstanceOfBoth;
          verifyGenerator = (VerifyGenerator)&createInstanceOfBoth;              
      }

      Enroll* getEnroll () { return enrollGenerator (); }
      Verify* getVerify () { return verifyGenerator (); }

      EnrollGenerator enrollGenerator;
      VerifyGenerator verifyGenerator;
};
```

And here's the problem.  When I call `getEnroll()` on my `Registry` object and invoke `enroll()` on the object that's returned, I see the proper, expected output: `Enrolling.`.  But when I call `getVerify()` and invoke `verify()` on the object that's returned, *the `enroll()` method is executed again*!

Code:

```
int main () {
   Registry registry;
   Enroll *enroller;
   Verify *verifier;

   enroller = registry.getEnroll ();
   verifier = registry.getVerify ();
   enroller->enroll ();
   verifier->verify ();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enrolling.
Enrolling.
```

I've noticed that if I change the order of `Enroll` and `Verify` in the declaration of the `Both` class (`class Both : public Verify, public Enroll {...}`), the opposite effect will happen:

```
Verifying.
Verifying.
```

I've identified a workaround in which, instead of using a single `createInstanceOfBoth()` function to create my `Enroll` and `Verify` objects, I use two differently named functions with the same body but different return types:

```
Enroll* createInstanceOfEnroll () {
   return new Both();
}
Verify* createInstanceOfVerify () {
   return new Both();
}
```

Then, in the Registry class, I create my function pointers to these functions instead:

```
Registry () {
    enrollGenerator = &createInstanceOfEnroll;
    verifyGenerator = &createInstanceOfVerify;        
}
```

When I run the program now, I get the expected output:

```
Enrolling.
Verifying.
```

My question is this: why doesn't the first way of doing it work?  I suspect that it has something to do with casting `createInstanceOfBoth()` to a function pointer with a different return type, but I don't fully understand exactly what's happening.  I'm fine with using my workaround at the moment, but I'm curious: is there a way of doing this with just the single `createInstanceOfBoth()` function instead of having to use two identical functions but with different return types?

To save the time and hassle of putting this together into a compilable example, I've posted this code to https://gist.github.com/833304 for download.

Comment: I'm hoping this is an academic curiosity ...

Comment: Long question, but nicely laid out and easy reading... well done.

Comment: @AJG85: It is.  I encountered this sort of tangentially in the course of exploring ways to dynamically instantiate subclasses of `Base` and even though the production code won't involve anything like this example, it confounded me enough that I couldn't just drop it and move on until I understood what was going on.

Comment: Ah well it is an interesting quirk. Sounds like a possible situation where you could use the abstract factory design pattern ... downcasting is worth avoiding as is multiple inheritance except for very specific situations, but that's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That function pointer cast (treating a function returning `Both*` as returning `Verify*` or `Enroll*`) is incorrect; with multiple inheritance, the different base classes within an object do not necessarily start at the beginning of the object.  The function pointer cast is not doing the offsetting operation that is required for the derived-to-base pointer casts from `Both*` to the base pointer types.

You can have a single `createInstanceOfBoth` function, but it would need to return `Both*`; the code that calls it would then do the derived-to-base cast with that result.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  I've been racking my brain over this little detail for hours, but now that you explain it, it's embarrassingly obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: Good explanation.  "the different base classes within an object do not necessarily start at the beginning of the object" - only one can so that statements a little conservative ;-)

Comment: @Tony: is there a requirement that any of them start at the beginning of the derived object?  I believe there is for single inheritance, but am not sure for multiple inheritance.

Comment: that I don't know... I thought you meant there might not be 2+ and was thinking there can't be, but good query whether it need even be 1. I don't see any particular reason the Standard would prohibit a compiler from putting something there, given the virtual functions mean it's not a POD type needing layout compatibility with anything from the C or hardware device world.

Comment: I still dont understand how to have the correct function called